# Как настроить vimrc файл так, чтобы он не заменял табы на пробелы в Makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile, vim

Мне бы хотелось настроить vimrc файл так, чтобы он заменял в начале строке табы на пробелы в любом файле, кроме Makefile. Вопрос: можно ли вообще это сделать, и если можно, то как?

Comment: Детально описать не могу, но можно, на сколько знаю. Ищите в сторону ```autocommand``` в части  поведения при открытии файла, и ```FileType```, чтобы действия выполнялись только для нужного типа файлов

Comment: Так он так и работает по умолчанию. Возможно вы что-то неудачно поменяли в конфиге

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
autocmd FileType make setlocal tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 noexpandtab
```

Делает настройки для отдельного окна или буфера. Главное -- `noexpandtab`. `:h autocommand`

Comment: Для предотвращения дублирования автокоманды при повторном запуске `vimrc` нужно использовать `:autocmd!` со знаком восклицания, которая перед установкой команды очищает предыдущее значение(я) для данного события и шаблона. `:h autocmd-remove`.